# How to get all simple properties of an object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I was wondering how I would go about getting all types of an object, that do not point to another class.

e.g. this would include string, int, datetime etc
     but would not include a pointer to collections, or other custom classes

I have the following, but it doesn't seem to return strings:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeOfObject.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties.Where(p => !p.PropertyType.IsClass))
{
}
```

As asked by Leri - I plan to take a primitive copy of an object, with NO collections/classes etc. SO it has to contain all primitive types, strings, datetime and whatever other ones exist.

Comment: Why do you want it? Sounds like you are doing some mapping.. Adding larger context will let us give more exact answers.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. I know how to get properties, but I didn't know a good way to get specifi properties as per my question. Leri - I have updated my question at the bottom

Answer (score 7):

Because `String` is a class, not a struct like `Int32` and `Double` etc

If you want everything that's not a class but including string, just specify that!

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in 
         properties.Where(p => !p.PropertyType.IsClass 
                                  || p.PropertyType == typeof(String)))
{
}
```

Comment: || p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)

Comment: What other in-built types would be missing from this other than string? Emil also mentions DateTime, are there any others?

Comment: Emil's comment is wrong, DateTime is not a class, so you don't have to have an exception for that. However, as I said in my answer, you can have a struct (which is "not a class" and will pass your test) which references other classes.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will also give you all structs, which can in themselves contain references to collections etc., so it will not do.

Your best bet is probably to ask for IsPrimitive (which gives you int, short etc.), and add any other known types you want, such as string, DateTime etc.

Comment: Ah ok, I never thought about Structs. In this case I won't actually have any structs, but for future proofing it would be best to take care of them just now. So, other than string, datetime, what would not be included in "IsPrimitive"? And what about nullable types?

Comment: MSDN says: "The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single."
Nullable types are going to be tricky, basically you'll have to get the generic type definition - `p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)`. However, a nullable can contain any value type, so you need to check your list of allowed types against the type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to do a mixture of a couple of solutions here.

Firstly, due to the issues with structs etc I have decided to keep a list of allowed types as mentioned by Leri.

Secondly, I have written a method to deal with the nullables as per Luaan's comment.

So the solution is as follows:

The code for iterating through the properties

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
 if (this.IsTypeASimpleType(property.PropertyType) &&
     property.CanWrite)
 {
 }
}
```

Then the code for checking if the type is correct

```
    private bool IsTypeASimpleType(Type typeToCheck)
    {
        var typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(this.GetUnderlyingType(typeToCheck));

        switch (typeCode)
        {
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
            case TypeCode.Byte:
            case TypeCode.Char:
            case TypeCode.DateTime:
            case TypeCode.Decimal:
            case TypeCode.Double:
            case TypeCode.Int16:
            case TypeCode.Int32:
            case TypeCode.Int64:
            case TypeCode.SByte:
            case TypeCode.Single:
            case TypeCode.String:
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

And the code to deal with nullables

```
    private Type GetUnderlyingType(Type typeToCheck)
    {
        if (typeToCheck.IsGenericType &&
            typeToCheck.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeToCheck);
        }
        else
        {
            return typeToCheck;
        }
    }
```

Now, the switch statement could have been changed to a list of allowed types, but the end game would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with your refined question, the better answer is this:  if you are in a position to call GetType() on a variable, that returns an object and you can reflect on that object to obtain the underlying type.  You can also ask if the type is an instance of some other existing type, which can be helpful for determining runtime type safety ("will my code throw an exception if I treat this entity like an object of type Cat?")

So I think what you want to do is to call GetType().  Then there are many things you can do with the returned type object.  One of them is to test for exact match, for example this way: "if(x.GetType().Equals(typeof(int)))....

There are actually a few ways to do this and all of them work.  The exact match I just did is very rigid.  But notice that you can use typeof(int) to get a Type object that will be the true underlying type representation for the int type, even though an int is a base type in C# and hence something of type int isn't an object -- at runtime it is represented by value and not by reference.  This works because typeof() is resolved at compile time.

So I think for your purposes this may be what you need to do.